# Can't remove unwanted character from HTML using Replace

Tags: html, css, vb.net, replace, stringbuilder

I am having an issue with HTML when opening a current HTML file and replacing what I need to using a StringBuilder... Below is the bit of code I am using to do this...

```
  'Lets replace the grid information!'
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.AppendLine(" <table>")
    sb.AppendLine("<tr>")
    '  sb.AppendLine("<th>")
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        sb.AppendLine("   <th>" + column.HeaderText + "</th>")
    Next
    ' sb.AppendLine("</th>")
    sb.AppendLine(" </tr>")
    sb.AppendLine("</table")

    HTML.Replace("%TABLE%", sb.ToString)
```

Everything is working so far, only issue I am having is getting rid of the "<" by the customers name field... I know it is because of the replace; it is adding an extra one there. But if I take it out of the append line, my grid goes out of wack... Here is a screen shot of this...

[image: ERROR IM HAVING]

Here is the source of the HTML file I am grabbing and then replacing what I need too...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Invoice %Invoice%</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=%STYLE%>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("style.css");
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Invoice %Invoice%</h1>
        <address>
            <p>%Business%</p>

        </address>
        <img src="file:///%Image%" alt="" align="right">
    </header>
    <article>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>Recipient</h1>
        <address>
        <p>%Company%</p>
            <p>%Contact%</p>
            <p>%Address%</p>
        </address>
        <table class="meta">
            <tr>
                <th><span>Invoice #</span></th>
                <td><span>%Invoice%</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Date</span></th>
                <td><span>%Date%</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Amount Paid</span></th>
                <td><span id="prefix">$</span><span>0.00</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Amount Due</span></th>
                <td><span id="prefix">$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%TABLE%>   THIS IS WHERE I SEND THE TABLE TO!
        </article>
    <aside>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1><span>Additional Notes</span></h1>
        <div contenteditable>
          <p align ='center'>A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming HTML is a string the replace function returns a string result, so you need:

```
HTML = HTML.Replace("%TABLE%", sb.ToString)
```

And as per the answer from 
[pickypg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706724/pickypg) you probably really need:

```
HTML = HTML.Replace("<%TABLE%>", sb.ToString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it still didn't work. It is still adding the extra "<" at the beginning of the table...

Comment: I agree with pickypg, and just updated my answer to reflect you probably need both changes in combination.

Answer (score 1):

Your string in the raw HTML is literally `<%TABLE%>`, but you are only replacing `%TABLE%`.

The end of your `StringBuilder` string ends in `</table` without the `>`, but it starts with `<table>`. This is the source of it, but you should fix the previous issue along with appropriately closing the table's tag.

Comment: Actually its already replaced if you look at the markup.... ">" this is replaced already and isn't the issue... Thanks Though!

Comment: What is replaced? The markup has `<%TABLE%>`, but you only replace `%TABLE%`, which means that you have `<>` after you do the replacement. This is somewhat lucky because `</table` lines up with the ending `>`, which leaves only the unmatched, starting `<`. That is what you are seeing.